# Push notification not working - Android

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-pendingintent

I am trying to send a push notification on a button click event. But don't know why, but it is not working. It doesn't show any error though. Can anybody find any error in the code?

```
public class Verify extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String TAG=Verify.class.getSimpleName();
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
private static final int uniqueID=12345;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify);
    notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notification.setAutoCancel(true);
}

public void onVerify(View v)
{
    this.defineNotification();
//other code follows
}

public void defineNotification()
{
    notification.setContentTitle("Successfully Signed Up");
    notification.setContentText("Hi, you just Signed Up as a Vendor");
    notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,OtherActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(uniqueID,notification.build());
    //Log.i(TAG, "coming here in notification");
}
```

Here is the Android Manifest Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sachinparashar.xyz">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SignUp"
        android:label="SignUp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Verify"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_verify"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".VendorDetails"
        android:label="Vendor Details"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".OrderTypes"
        android:label="Orders"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

</application>
```

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174963/notification-sound-not-work-for-api-10-android/34175318#34175318

Comment: I have exactly the same code but it's not working for me.

Comment: There are handlers and sender classes missing...Try this....https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Cloud-Messaging#add-gcm-permissions

Comment: How `defineNotification()` method is being called????

Comment: from the OnVerify() method which is a button click method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this :

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

with this :

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: U are missing notificationIcon that's why u r facing this problem please add this in your code notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

Comment: Yes, it worked. I thought omitting icon won't be a problem. I set it to R.mipmap.ic_launcher and world's coolest app is now ready. ;)   Thank you @kapil

Answer (score 0):

Insted of

`PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

use

`PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(Verify.this,0,intent,0);`

Comment: Have you changed this to verify.this

Comment: On what api you are checking the notification??

Comment: remove this line `notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
`